# How to travel between planets on the same star system in Sci-Fi?

Tags: planets, science-fiction, space-travel, faster-than-light

We know, that to travel to another star systems, we need to  use FTL for traveling. But if you need to travel to another planet in the same star system, what type of travel should be used? Is it worth using fuel costing engines like warp drive (because  it uses "exotic matter", a lot of it)?

Comment: Can  you spend some more words in defining your context? Worth has to be measured with respect to a context: a horse was a valid transportation few centuries ago, nowadays and in certain countries no more.

Comment: *"We know, that to travel to another star systems, we need to use FTL for traveling."* Not necessarily. Even that depends on context; for example, a very long-lived species able to achieve a velocity that is a very large fraction of *c* living in a densely populated part of the galaxy might not care about travel time to nearby star systems, while if you change any of those assumptions, travel time may become a very relevant consideration.

Comment: It heavily depends on the amount of exotic matter used, the efficiency (does a short trip take almost as much matter as a long one?) and the availability. If exotic matter is ludicrously expensive and hard to get and most of the usage is starting/stopping the FTL then the answer is use whatever STL drives available. If it's not expensive, relatively easy to get and usage is mostly based on distance traveled the answer is "why wouldnt you use it, it saves months if not years of travel".

Comment: For saying "worth" I meant to say: "Does it worth, to spend same amout of exotic matter that used to create warp burble for a long inter-stellar trip, to use for travel to another planet instead. You use same amount of exotic matter, no matter where you travel, cause it's used to create warp burble. Or maybe should I use abother FTL system for my story?

Comment: @Egidajus Commenting clarifications only works slightly, you really need to edit the question for clarity if you want good answers that take new data into account.

Comment: You question boils down to "what fictional propulsion system should I use compared to the fictional FTL drives but I'm providing no details to compare them".  That's asking WB to write your story and do your basic research for you.

Comment: You hitchhike. Don't forget to bring your towel.

Answer (score 1):

An energy efficient method would be to use [solar sailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail) or to convert solar energy to one of the different [electro propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrically_powered_spacecraft_propulsion) engines. All technologies are either used or existant, but not efficient enough yet and depend on the so far most reliable resource you can "obtain" in a solar system, which is a sun. Those methods also have the potencial to reach high velocity over a relatively small amount of time.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Instinct, and nice answer! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Is (comparatively) short-range teleportation like the transporters in Star Trek an option? Perhaps there could be wormhole-like gates similar to those in Stargate.

If we’re looking for “super fast” instead of instantaneous, I am imagining something along the lines of a railgun or maglev launcher that propels vehicles based on a trajectory calculated to put them in some sort of deceleration field or other object that uses magnetics to influence trajectory or momentum in the orbit of the destination planet. I imagine the lack of friction makes maintaining momentum easy to the point of not burning fuel once sufficiently launched.

Comment: Railguns or mass drivers do not make good space transportation systems. The accelerations would kill humans and the maximum velocity attained only about 4 km/s. Other forms of propulsion would be better. Say, ion or plasma drives. If they possess FTL, then there should be better forms of sublight propulsion.